# Issues with whitespaces and font-size while generating PDF using velocity template

Tags: itext, velocity

I am using an older version of itext-2.x.x and velocity-2.x for one of my projects.

GOAL - Need to generate PDF using velocity template.

ISSUE1 - The spaces in the velocity template are visible on the PDF generated. Below is an example of my velocity template -

```
<tr>
    <td>
        Test Content
    </td>
<tr>
```

is generating the spaces in the cell on the PDF. However, when the same code in velocity template is written as below -

```
<tr><td>Test Content</td></tr>
```

the spaces are not showing up in the cell on the PDF.

The same velocity template is generating the my emails with proper formatting. So, I can conclude that the issue might be with generating PDF.

ISSUE2 - The font written in velocity template is not showing up on PDF. Below is the code snippet -

```
<tr>
   <td style="font-size: 12pt">
       Test Content
   </td>
</tr>
```

However, if I am trying to use  tag with size attribute, I am able to achieve the results.

Can some please help me in understand the behavior of iText while generating the PDF suing velocity.

Comment: Your HTML code wasn't visible. You should have used marked for code. iText 2.x.y is no longer supported. The Velocity project isn't affiliated with iText in any way. Hence tagging the question with itextpdf was wrong: I also corrected this. It is not clear which HTML rendering engine Velocity is using. It's certainly not iText's XML Worker. Maybe the `HTMLWorker` class is used in which case you've reached a dead end. `HTMLWorker` has been abandoned in favor of XML Worker.

Comment: As Bruno said, you are not only using an obsolete tool, `HTMLWorker`, you are using an obsolete version of iText. All of the problems you are talking about can be addressed with a newer version of iText as well as the supported `XMLWorker` for parsing HTML. That said, you've already answered your own questions. Don't put spaces in your table cells and use the HTML attribute for font sizes. You *must* completely ignore how your browser renders HTML, that doesn't matter. iText doesn't "render" HTML, it converts HTML tags into PDF commands.

Comment: Thank you Guys for replying! Regarding my first query, if I am following the second pattern and writing everything in one line then the code will not be in readable format. And this does not seem to be proper approach as the "Test Content" is basically dynamic content. And regarding the second query, when I try font-size CSS property to generate an email (using Velocity), the used font size shows up properly in email and when the same font-size CSS property is used to generate PDF, it does not work.